# Azure error: One or more errors occurred

Tags: azure, ionic-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

We are working on Ionic project with an Asp.Net Core MVC. After calling 2 methods in repository GetStoryCountForProfile() and SavedStoriesCountForProfileAsync(), the app stooped to work with the error message: One or more errors occurred when its called form Azure. In local it works without any error.

I call them like this:

```
response.ResultObject.MyStories = await _storyRepository.GetStoryCountForProfile(response.ResultObject.Profile.Id);
response.ResultObject.SavedStories = await _savedStoryRepository.SavedStoriesCountForProfileAsync(response.ResultObject.Profile.Id);
response.ResultObject.Followers = (await _followRepository.GetFollowersAsync(response.ResultObject.Profile.Id)).Number;
response.ResultObject.Following = (await _followRepository.GetFollowedAsync(response.ResultObject.Profile.Id)).Number;
```

The repositories:

```
public async Task<int> GetStoryCountForProfile(int profileID)
        {
            int result = 0;

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = SqlAccess.BuildCommand("StoryGetAllForProfile");

                command.Parameters["@ProfileID"].Value = profileID;

                DataTable datafromSQL = SqlAccess.ExecuteDataTable(command);

                if (datafromSQL.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    List<StoryEntity> stories = TableToObject.MapToList<StoryEntity>(datafromSQL);
                    return await Task.FromResult(stories.Count);
                }
            }

            return await Task.FromResult(result);
        }

public async Task<int> SavedStoriesCountForProfileAsync(int profileID)
        {
            int result = 0;

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = SqlAccess.BuildCommand("GetSavedStoriesForProfile");

                command.Parameters["@ProfileID"].Value = profileID;

                DataTable datafromSQL = SqlAccess.ExecuteDataTable(command);

                if (datafromSQL.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    List<StoryEntity> stories = TableToObject.MapToList<StoryEntity>(datafromSQL);
                    return await Task.FromResult(result);
                }
            }

            return await Task.FromResult(result);
        }
```

If i comment the lines where I call those two methods, the app is working, or put there any number.

I tried to make them synchronous, not solved the problem.

What did I miss?!

thnx

Comment: "One or more errors occurred " -> that is all the details you get? Gonna be hard for us to help. BTW: remove the `async` keyword and just return `Task.FromResult(x)` will do as well.

Comment: That's all. That is a problem. There is nothing in internal log, nothing on Azure logs.

Comment: Do you have any unhandled exception handling and logging in place? What if you put try/catch around the methods you call?

Comment: I tried now to make all calls synchronous, and that also not helped me.

I have try/catch i service layer, and nothing, no exception.